# The qvolume of an integer

Tags: code-golf, complex-numbers

It is ancient knowledge that every non-negative integer can be rewritten as the sum of four squared integers. For example the number 1 can be expressed as \$0^2+0^2+0^2+1^2\$. Or, in general, for any non-negative integer \$n\$, there exist integers \$a,b,c,d\$ such that

$$n = a^2+b^2+c^2+d^2$$

[Joseph-Louis Lagrange](https://pg-astro.fr/grands-astronomes/le-grand-siecle/joseph-louis-lagrange.html) proved this in the 1700s and so it is often called [Lagrange's Theorem](https://www.britannica.com/science/Lagranges-four-square-theorem).

This is sometimes discussed in relation to quaternions – a type of number  discovered by [William Hamilton](https://www.maths.tcd.ie/pub/HistMath/People/Hamilton/) in the 1800s, represented as $$w+x\textbf{i}+y\textbf{j}+z\textbf{k}$$ where \$w,x,y,z\$ are real numbers, and \$\textbf{i}, \textbf{j}\$ and \$\textbf{k}\$ are distinct imaginary units that don't multiply commutatively. Specifically, it is discussed in relation to squaring each component of the quaternion $$w^2+x^2+y^2+z^2$$This quantity is sometimes called the [norm, or squared norm](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3174308/norm-of-quaternion), or also [quadrance](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=g22jAtg3QAk). Some [modern proofs](https://www2.gwu.edu/~spwm/erin_alissa.pdf) of Lagrange's Theorem use quaternions.

[Rudolf Lipschitz](http://www-history.mcs.st-andrews.ac.uk/Biographies/Lipschitz.html) studied quaternions with only integer components, called Lipschitz quaternions. Using quadrance, we can imagine that every Lipschitz quaternion can be thought of having a friend in the integers. For example quaternion \$0+0\textbf{i}+0\textbf{j}+1\textbf{k}\$ can be thought of as associated with the integer \$1=0^2+0^2+0^2+1^2\$. Also, if we go backwards, then every integer can be thought of as having a friend in the Lipschitz quaternions.

But there is an interesting detail of Lagrange's theorem – the summation is not unique. Each integer may have several different sets of four squares that can be summed to create it. For example, the number 1 can be expressed in 4 ways using non-negative integers (let us only consider non-negatives for this challenge):
$$1=0^2+0^2+0^2+1^2$$
$$1=0^2+0^2+1^2+0^2$$
$$1=0^2+1^2+0^2+0^2$$
$$1=1^2+0^2+0^2+0^2$$

The summands are always squares of 0, or 1, but they can be in different positions in the expression.

For this challenge, let us also "sort" our summands lowest to highest, to eliminate duplicates, so that we could consider, for this exercise, that 1 only has one way of being represented as the sum of four squares:

$$1=0^2+0^2+0^2+1^2$$

Another example is the number 42, which can be expressed in four ways (again, only considering non-negative a,b,c,d, and eliminating duplicate component arrangements)

$$42=0^2+1^2+4^2+5^2$$
$$42=1^2+1^2+2^2+6^2$$
$$42=1^2+3^2+4^2+4^2$$
$$42=2^2+2^2+3^2+5^2$$

What if we imagine each of these different ways of expressing an integer as being associated to a specific quaternion? Then we could say the number 42 is associated with these four quaternions:

$$0+1\textbf{i}+4\textbf{j}+5\textbf{k}$$
$$1+1\textbf{i}+2\textbf{j}+6\textbf{k}$$
$$1+3\textbf{i}+4\textbf{j}+4\textbf{k}$$
$$2+2\textbf{i}+3\textbf{j}+5\textbf{k}$$

If we imagine the standard computer graphics interpretation of a quaternion, where \$\textbf{i}\$, \$\textbf{j}\$ and \$\textbf{k}\$ are vectors in three dimensional [Euclidean](https://play.google.com/books/reader?id=5lN1sy51SwYC&hl=en&pg=GBS.PA6) space, and so the \$x\$, \$y\$ and \$z\$ components of the quaternion are 3 dimensional [Cartesian](https://mathinsight.org/cartesian_coordinates) coordinates, then we can imagine that each integer, through this thought process, can be associated with a set of 3 dimensional coordinates in space. For example, the number 42 is associated with the following four \$(x,y,z)\$ coordinates: $$(1,4,5),(1,2,6),(3,4,4),(2,3,5)$$

This can be thought of as a point cloud, or a set of points in space. Now, one interesting thing about a set of finite points in space is that you can always draw a minimal bounding box around them – a box that is big enough to fit all the points, but no bigger. If you imagine the box as being an ordinary box aligned with the \$x,y,z\$ axes, it is called an [axis-aligned bounding box](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Games/Techniques/3D_collision_detection). The bounding box also has a volume, calculable by determining its width, length, and height, and multiplying them together.

We can then imagine the volume of a bounding box for the points formed by our quaternions. For the integer 1, we have, using the criteria of this exercise, one quaternion whose quadrance is 1, \$0+0\textbf{i}+0\textbf{j}+1\textbf{k}\$. This is a very simple point cloud, it only has one point, so it's bounding box has volume 0. For the integer 42, however, we have four quaternions, and so four points, around which we can draw a bounding box. The minimum point of the box is \$(1,2,4)\$ and the maximum is \$(3,4,6)\$ resulting in a width, length, and height of 2, 2, and 2, giving a volume of 8.

Let's say that for an integer \$n\$, the qvolume is the volume of the axis-aligned bounding box of all the 3D points formed by quaternions that have a quadrance equal to \$n\$, where the components of the quaternion \$w+x\textbf{i}+y\textbf{j}+z\textbf{k}\$ are non-negative and \$w<=x<=y<=z\$.

Create a program or function that, given a single non-negative integer \$n\$, will output \$n\$'s qvolume.

Examples:

```
input -> output
0 -> 0
1 -> 0
31 -> 4
32 -> 0
42 -> 8
137 -> 96
1729 -> 10032
```

This is code-golf, smallest number of bytes wins.

Comment: what do i need to add? i meant to indicate that smallest number of bytes would win

Comment: You forgot the code-golf tag, I helped you add it

Comment: This is a nice challenge but it would be even better IMHO if it was a bit less verbose. Also, beware of [irrelevant links](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9336/58563) (I'm not saying that all your links are irrelevant, but only a few of them really bring meaningful information for the challenge, while the other ones are just distracting).

Comment: Yes, but why take only i, j, k as 3D space but not 4D space?

Comment: A related question which required to output 4 numbers which square sum to the input: https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/28169/four-squares-together

Comment: @tsh because Quaternions don't necessarily represent a 4 dimensional Euclidean space. Hamilton discovered them while searching for a way to work with 3 dimensional space. It would be possible to do a 4d version but i was pondering their use in 3d space when i made the question

Comment: Is it just a coincidence that the sum of coefficients of deduplicated quaternions is equal to its number? Ie. 42? Or does it just follow from the way quaternions are? Sorry if I am asking the obvious, I have no mathematics background.

Comment: To be honest, you don't need quaternions to introduct the problem. If you just want to introduce some interesting (mildly-relevant) fact, just spare one paragraph on it, or maybe two.

Answer (score 13):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), <s>67</s> 58 bytes

```
Volume@BoundingRegion[Rest/@PowersRepresentations[#,4,2]]&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HYuxCsMgFAD3fMWDQiYhjRFCh4LkC4JDFusg7cMK9VnU0KH0263tcMctF2y5Y7DFX211cIZL3eJjDyiXuNPNk1PofCStMJdBrvGFKSt8JsxIpW2Rsj4wwbgxfV2TpyKdFLzr/q3dIOF9ZDAymH5wBqIxTnPTzE8fU78)

```
                         ...&   Pure function:
PowersRepresentations[#,4,2]    Get the sorted reprs. of # as sums of 4 2nd powers
Rest/@                         Drop the first coordinate of each
BoundingRegion[...]            Find the bounding region, a Cuboid[] or Point[].
                               By default Mathematica finds an axis-aligned cuboid.
Volume                         Find volume; volume of a Point[] is 0.
```

Comment: wow, i had no idea that something like PowersRepresentations would be a built in in a language. i actually thought about making a challenge to show the different ways to sum an integer as four squares but im glad i did not.

Comment: Lol, [Mathematica even has a builtin for determining goats in an image](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/71680/52210), so having a builtin for this really doesn't surprise me. xD

Answer (score 8):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 17 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
Żœċ4²S⁼ɗƇ⁸ZḊṢ€I§P
```

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##AS4A0f9qZWxsef//xbvFk8SLNMKyU@KBvMmXxofigbha4biK4bmi4oKsScKnUP///zQy)** (pretty slow - make it fast enough for all the test cases [with a leading `½`](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///Q3qO7j04@0m1yaFPwo8Y9J6cfa3/UuCPq4Y6uhzsXPWpa43loecD/w@1A1v//0YY6CsYgbKSjYALEhsbmQMLcyDIWAA))

#### How?

```
Żœċ4²S⁼ɗƇ⁸ZḊṢ€I§P - Link: non-negative integer, n    e.g. 27
Ż                 - zero-range                            [0,1,2,...,27]
   4              - literal four                          4
 œċ               - combinations with replacement         [[0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,1],...,[0,0,0,27],[0,0,1,1],[0,0,1,2],...,[27,27,27,27]]
        Ƈ         - filter keep those for which:          e.g.: [0,1,1,5]
       ɗ          -   last three links as a dyad:
    ²             -     square (vectorises)                     [0,1,1,25]
     S            -     sum                                     27
      ⁼  ⁸        -     equal to? chain's left argument, n      1
                  -                                       -> [[0,1,1,5],[0,3,3,3],[1,1,3,4]]
          Z       - transpose                             [[0,0,1],[1,3,1],[1,3,3],[5,3,4]]
           Ḋ      - dequeue                               [[1,3,1],[1,3,3],[5,3,4]]
            Ṣ€    - sort each                             [[1,1,3],[1,3,3],[3,4,5]]
              I   - incremental differences (vectorises)  [[ 0,2 ],[ 2,0 ],[ 1,1 ]]
               §  - sum each                              [2,2,2]
                P - product                               8
```

Answer (score 6):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), <s>132</s> 123 bytes

```hs
z=zipWith
(!)=foldr1.z
h n=[0..n]
f n|p<-[[c,b,a]|a<-h n,b<-h a,c<-h b,d<-h c,a^2+b^2+c^2+d^2==n]=product$z(-)(max!p)$min!p
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZYrRCoIwFIbvfYojeKG0iVoghXuArroRuhCFuSWOdBvTKIbvbhoEYQd@Pv7vPy0d7reum2dLrNBXMbaO7wakUR03cWidFiQpojCUpdOAnHSGi4KhGtFyohleVlSvoIitqBFfwRCtkl29hC3hVUKILIk2ij/Y6FkfB35PX64OvF5IV889FZJw5cBy2gg5ggcNRJseb/r@TyQbcdiKeJ9@DMaQKwVDp57QKAP5@QIn/zv9/KfJcX4D)

Pretty straightforward solution. Brute force all the possible solutions by iterating over all the values from 0 to n (way overkill but shorter bytecount). I output the point as a list so we can use @Lynn's magic `(!)` operator. That operator collapses each dimension with the function on the left side so `max!p` returns a list of size 3 which consists of the maximums along each dimension and `min!p` does the same for minimum. Then we just find the minimum size in each dimension (by subtracting the min value from the max with `z(-)`) and multiply them together.

Thanks a lot to @Lynn for taking off 9 bytes with some folding zip magic!

Comment: I shaved off a few bytes by forgoing the transposition in favor of some `zipWith` logic. [123 bytes](https://tio.run/##ZYrRCoIwFIbvfYojeKG0iVoghXuArroRuhCFuSWOdBvTKIbvbhoEYQd@Pv7vPy0d7reum2dLrNBXMbaO7wakUR03cWidFiQpojCUpdOAnHSGi4KhGtFyohleVlSvoIitqBFfwRCtkl29hC3hVUKILIk2ij/Y6FkfB35PX64OvF5IV889FZJw5cBy2gg5ggcNRJseb/r@TyQbcdiKeJ9@DMaQKwVDp57QKAP5@QIn/zv9/KfJcX4D)

Answer (score 5):

## [Sledgehammer](https://github.com/tkwa/Sledgehammer) 0.2, 12 bytes

```
⡌⢎⣟⡊⢘⣚⡏⡨⠍⠁⡇⠨
```

Use with Mathematica 11.2 and [this version](https://github.com/tkwa/Sledgehammer/tree/137f71a5e3f4ddd8d008f0811e3d1d3bea7ebb5e) of Sledgehammer, which predates the challenge. See edit history for a version that works in version 0.3, which has a GUI and generates a Mathematica expression.

This pushes the input to the stack and calls the sequence of commands

```
{intLiteral[4], intLiteral[2], call["PowersRepresentations", 3], call["Thread", 1], call["Rest", 1], call["Thread", 1], call["BoundingRegion", 1], call["Volume", 1]}
```

which is equivalent to evaluating the following Wolfram code derived from my [Wolfram Language answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/186161/39328):

```
Volume[BoundingRegion[Thread@Rest@Thread@PowersRepresentations[#, 4, 2]]]&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LY29CoMwFEZ3n@JCoVOgVQvSghB8ArE/S5oh6CUGNJHkSofSZ09j6XAOZ/jgmxWNOCsyvYp3u3hH2BO/To6yTULCpYZf5TLTUMMzPty0zigat9rBWN2hNs6K2@hRDbzDQPzfrXuhDx0uHgNaSifOBrFjcGJQSCn3sfXGktAHDu8jg5xBuVGkRSIvq6SqOH9k/AI)

Comment: does this require mathematica to test it?

Comment: @don bright Yes, the repository has instructions. It's a work in progress so not very user-friendly yet. After running setup.wls you can test either with wolframscript or interactive_app.wls.

Comment: Is Sledgehammer code just a compressed form of its respective Mathematica?

Comment: @Downgoat Yes. I plan to implement a golfing library, but currently it decompresses to plain Mathematica.

Comment: Surely you can't use a language that is newer than the challenge even if you claim that it makes it larger? Why not use the older version? If the older doesn't work, I don't see how the bytecount can be compared.

Comment: @pipe The older version should work (now that I think of it, the code is exactly the same on one older version), but I'd have to download it and run setup again. (The changes since then have mostly been writing the GUI and refactoring code with no major change in functionality.) Since this answer is shortest it seems important to prove the eligibility, so I'll do that tomorrow morning.

Comment: can i plug the output of sledgehammer into the Try It Online wolfram language?

Comment: @donbright not anymore, I edited the answer to use an older version of Sledgehammer that executes directly instead of building a WL function.

Comment: lets say someone didnt have access to mathematica, how would they test it?

Comment: @donbright TIO.run doesn't support the Wolfram Cloud, which you need to run the setup function. I could add the file save.mx that setup generates to the repository and write a version of the app that you can paste into tio.run, but as of now there's no way to test.

I realize there are issues with a language most people cannot test, so I'm willing to delete this answer if it's unsatisfying to the community, until I have a stable version that can be put on TIO.run.

Comment: can anyone else run this? i kind of would like to verify it works before giving it the ol' checkmark.

Comment: better question... is there some way to rent mathematica for a few hours, for a few dollars?

Comment: ok so i can get a trial version of mathematica for free for 30 days... will sledgehammer run on linux?

Comment: @donbright Probably, though I didn't test it because I don't have Linux.

Answer (score 4):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 138 bytes

```python
q=lambda n,x=0,*t:[t]*(n==0)if t[3:]else q(n-x*x,x,x,*t)+q(n,x+1,*t+(0,)*(x>n))
p=1
for l in zip(*q(input()))[:3]:p*=max(l)-min(l)
print p
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FY5BCoMwFET3OUVw9X@MkGihEEgvIi5sGzEQv9GmNO3lbWQG3rzdxG@aV2qPz@yD49q47B5VVR2bDeNyf46cZLZKimT6NAggaxX6iae@M4MLL8c3oCaLLM@IhHVxmWtddg1KooB8I0QWrWbTuvPAPfGfjyA28BTfCRCxN91gorDLmCFgs3gqYHH3lHg8zjuKadaVtuzSMt1d/w)

Recursively generates the reverse-sorted quaternions with the given norm, then takes the product between the max and min of all possible values in the first three indices.

`itertools` might have had a shot if it didn't use ridiculously long names like `itertools.combinations_with_replacement`

**[Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 161 bytes**

```python
from itertools import*
n=input();p=1
for l in zip(*[t[1:]for t in combinations_with_replacement(range(n+1),4)if sum(x*x for x in t)==n]):p*=max(l)-min(l)
print p
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FY5RCsIwEAX/c4qlX0lVMFUQKjmJiNSS2oVks6RbjF6@GngwMDDw@CNzom57zxg82N4XPzZNs005RUDxWVIKC2DklKVV5JB4FW2u7KyaUoYASPBF1u1Nbra/VyfVjSk@kQbBRMvjjTI/sucwjD56Ep0HenlNO2v2Z4MTLGvUpS1Q81JzMc7R3fTcujgUHcwhIv2hOCMJ8FZfHpVVp/86de6UPV1@)

This is why [`itertools` is never the answer](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5603/20260).

Answer (score 3):

## JavaScript (ES6),  <s>148</s>  143 bytes

```javascript
n=>(r=[[],[],[]]).map(a=>p*=a.length+~a.indexOf(1),(g=(s,k=0,a=[])=>a[3]?s||r.map(r=>r[a.pop()]=p=1):g(s-k*k,k,[...a,++k],k>s||g(s,k,a)))(n))|p
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fcxBbsIwEIXhfU/hpYc4Jk5QKUjjHqEHsLwYQWKoU9uyEeoi6tXTlgVIICG93af/fdKZyi4f06kOcd/PA84BNc9ojBWXWZBflDihTgskOfbBnQ7VD8lj2PffHwNXILhDXoTHRhAaC6jJdPa9TFO@tBl1NiRTTBwsJlSwdbzUfuGFF0ZKSaKqvBVe/yXu/0kQAPAAMKV5F0OJYy/H6PjAGWMNAFsuWa1Z8/KA6gl2N1w9YvukXN3w7R5Vt77i5vVO1brdXFU1TdfOvw)

### Commented

We initialize an array \$r\$ with 3 empty arrays.

```javascript
r = [ [], [], [] ]
```

For each valid value of \$x\$, we will set to \$1\$ the value at \$x+1\$ in the first array. Ditto for \$y\$ and \$z\$ with the 2nd and 3rd arrays respectively.

The dimensions of the bounding box will be deduced from the distance between the first and the last entry set to \$1\$ in these arrays.

#### Step 1

To fill \$r\$, we use the recursive function \$g\$.

```javascript
g = (              // g is a recursive function taking:
  s,               // s   = current sum, initially set to the input n
  k = 0,           // k   = next value to be squared
  a = []           // a[] = list of selected values
) =>               //
  a[3] ?           // if we have 4 values in a[]:
    s ||           //   if s is equal to zero (we've found a valid sum of 4 squares):
      r.map(r =>   //     for each array r[] in r[]:
        r[a.pop()] //       pop the last value from a[]
        = p = 1    //       and set the corresponding value in r[] to 1
                   //       (also initialize p to 1 for later use in step 2)
      )            //     end of map()
  :                // else:
    g(             //   do a recursive call:
      s - k * k,   //     subtract k² from s
      k,           //     pass k unchanged
      [...a, ++k], //     increment k and append it to a[]
      k > s ||     //     if k is less than or equal to s:
        g(s, k, a) //       do another recursive call with s and a[] unchanged
    )              //   end of outer recursive call
```

#### Step 2

We can now compute the product \$p\$ of the dimensions.

```javascript
r.map(a =>         // for each array a[] in r[]:
  p *=             //   multiply p by:
    a.length +     //     the length of a[]
    ~a.indexOf(1)  //     minus 1, minus the index of the first 1 in a[]
) | p              // end of map(); return p
```

Answer (score 2):

## [C# (Visual C# Interactive Compiler)](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/about-mono/releases/5.0.0/#csc), 229 bytes

```cs
a=>{uint b=0,c=~0U,d,e,f=0,g=0,h=0,i=c,j=c,k=c;for(;b*b<=a;b++)for(c=b;c*c<=a;c++)for(d=c;d*d<=a;d++)for(e=d;e*e<=a;e++)if(b*b+c*c+d*d+e*e==a){f=c>f?c:f;g=d>g?d:g;h=e>h?e:h;i=c<i?c:i;j=d<j?d:j;k=e<k?e:k;}return(f-i)*(g-j)*(h-k);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Zc49b4QwDAbgvb@iYwJBuo9Kp2Ictk5dq87gOCRE4iQOptP1r1NHuqVlsBU/rxOFbhXd4vaxTtSscVpMbtbj1qG95/NrjwdD@HP4Ms6w8TINUkEqIplRKiGBv84K@qJvsIO@LHWeCXuggjLRk5ysusJlck9idMAFZ2Kh6JU8U8q9UhZLSRA7ffdI1rdUexjQ2aF19QAB2YaW6wDykyZKGmFE14ySjpCQmyRpgsfMyzpPyldRF2qoRumhShoeG7x8z3Hhzzix8uqo9V847@X0X952cjxfdnQ5vYttvw)

Answer (score 2):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 18 bytes

```
Ý4ãʒnOQ}€{ζ¦ε{¥O}P
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ASgA1/9vc2FiaWX//3TDnTTDo8qSbk9RfeKCrHvOtsKmzrV7wqVPfVD//zQy)

Port of [Jonathan Allan's Jelly answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/186153/6484).

Answer (score 2):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 104 bytes

```hs
n%i=(-).maximum<*>minimum$[t!!i|t<-mapM(:[0..n])[0..3],sum(map(^2)t)==n,scanr1 max t==t]
f n=n%0*n%1*n%2
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FYxBCoMwFET3PcUXFBKJYlQoFNMb9ASSQhBtg/5PMBG66NmbxsXjDcMwb@PXedtipMIqVvEazcfigUN5R0tnyseQZfYbhgqNe7Db2NQ1aX6q08IfyFLPni0PXCkSfjK0S0g3EJQK@rIAKSqakgqZaCMaS6DA7ZYC5GnoYEkOZp2hT2FsBEgB3UkroE/I7qrjb1o28/Kxmpz7Aw)

*Thanks to Delfad0r for -1 byte and Lynn for 3 bytes*

To multiply the three dimensions, it turns out shortest to just write the product `f n=n%0*n%1*n%2` than to use any sort of loop. Here, `n%i` is the difference between the min and max of the `i`'th coordinate values, which are extracted with indexing `!!i`.

To generate the valid four-tuples, we take lists of four numbers from `[0..n]` whose squares sum to `n` and are in decreasing order. We check the reverse-sortedness of `t` with `scanr1 max t==t`, which sees if the running maximum of the reverse is itself, as Haskell doesn't have a built-in sort without a costly import. I tried various ways to recursively generate the four-tuples like in my Python answers, but they were all longer than this brute-force generate-and-filter way.

Comment: I'm probably missing something, but isn't it shorter to just compute `maximum l-minimum l`? [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JctBCoMwEIXhfU8xgoKWRIwK3Zgj9ASSQhDThiZDMBG68OxNR7r4mQ8e89LxvTqXM1b2cBOfU1HYI03c63Cv565tUU2laU4NisXd17TUj75JjZTI4qJxE@D1B5KUSUmS9bsHx73Fvy4GUGLVXbESVJ@9tggSwmYxQUnPAQzdpN8rjIS5YyAYDGc9g5ESw03l72KcfsbMlxB@ "Haskell – Try It Online")

Comment: Sure looks like it works! Feel free to post an answer and claim a bounty.

Comment: I am definitely *not* posting a new answer for such a trivial change, especially considering that before looking at your solution I was stuck at about 120 bytes. Also, I don't think my "golf" is worth a bounty. Sooner or later, I hope I'll manage to outgolf you in a non-trivial way; if that ever happens, I'll gladly accept your bounty :)

Comment: Some more small byte saves: `mapM(:[0..n])` saves two and `(-).maximum<*>minimum` saves one. (I'd also feel bad accepting a bounty just for this, ha.) [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FYxBCoMwFET3PcUXFBKJYlQoFNMb9ASSQhBtg/5PMBG66NmbxsXjDcMwb@PXedtipMIqVvEazcfigUN5R0tnyseQZfYbhgqNe7Db2NQ1aX6q08IfyFLPni0PXCkSfjK0S0g3EJQK@rIAKSqakgqZaCMaS6DA7ZYC5GnoYEkOZp2hT2FsBEgB3UkroE/I7qrjb1o28/Kxmpz7Aw "Haskell – Try It Online")

Answer (score 1):

## [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/), 164 bytes

```
. as$i|[range(.)]|[combinations(4)|select(map(.*.)|add==$i)|sort]|unique|[transpose[1:][]|sort|[.[:-1],.[1:]]|transpose|map(.[1]-.[0])|add//0]|reduce.[]as$j(1;.*$j)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PY5BCoMwEEWv0oWLROpoSqFg8STDLFIdSqQmmsTd3D21Lrr97/N481YKXGyqnGC0/s0KNAmOYXk5b7MLPqm7lsQfHrNa7KqgBi12moahcgcIMZPs3m07C@ZDkdaQGE1PSCcVBOwbQ1f4jST/j5w2NNQAdnQ627YjiTztIwPSUTUr84S6mnUpt8cX)

The pairwise reduction can probably be better. For lower numbers, null is substituted with `0` for consistent output.

Idea from Jonathan Allan's answer.

-1 from ovs.

Comment: The long `map` can be replaced with `[transpose[1:][]| ... ]` for -1